# All weights become NaN in basic Mnist keras example

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm running the Mnist example given at https://keras.io/examples/mnist_cnn/. After a few epochs, the accuracy drops to near zero and all layer weights become NaN.

```
x_train shape: (60000, 28, 28, 1)
60000 train samples
10000 test samples
Train on 60000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 69us/step - loss: 0.2202 - acc: 0.9321 - val_loss: 0.0594 - val_acc: 0.9815
Epoch 2/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 63us/step - loss: 0.0741 - acc: 0.9773 - val_loss: 0.0392 - val_acc: 0.9871
Epoch 3/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 63us/step - loss: 0.0345 - acc: 0.6064 - val_loss: 1.1921e-07 - val_acc: 0.0980
Epoch 4/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 63us/step - loss: 1.1921e-07 - acc: 0.0987 - val_loss: 1.1921e-07 - val_acc: 0.0980
Epoch 5/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 62us/step - loss: 1.1921e-07 - acc: 0.0987 - val_loss: 1.1921e-07 - val_acc: 0.0980
Epoch 6/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 63us/step - loss: 1.1921e-07 - acc: 0.0987 - val_loss: 1.1921e-07 - val_acc: 0.0980
Epoch 7/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 63us/step - loss: 1.1921e-07 - acc: 0.0987 - val_loss: 1.1921e-07 - val_acc: 0.0980
Epoch 8/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 63us/step - loss: 1.1921e-07 - acc: 0.0987 - val_loss: 1.1921e-07 - val_acc: 0.0980
Epoch 9/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 63us/step - loss: 1.1921e-07 - acc: 0.0987 - val_loss: 1.1921e-07 - val_acc: 0.0980
Epoch 10/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 63us/step - loss: 1.1921e-07 - acc: 0.0987 - val_loss: 1.1921e-07 - val_acc: 0.0980
Epoch 11/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 62us/step - loss: 1.1921e-07 - acc: 0.0987 - val_loss: 1.1921e-07 - val_acc: 0.0980
Epoch 12/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 63us/step - loss: 1.1921e-07 - acc: 0.0987 - val_loss: 1.1921e-07 - val_acc: 0.0980
Test loss: 1.1920930376163597e-07
Test accuracy: 0.098
```

```
for layer in model.layers:
    if len(layer.get_weights()) > 0 and np.all(np.isnan(layer.get_weights()[0])):
        print(layer.name)

Output:
conv2d_3
conv2d_4
dense_3
dense_4
```

TensorFlow 1.12.0
Keras 2.2.4
CUDA Version 10.0.130
cuDNN 7.3.1

Comment: I have run that example many times and never seen this behavior, did you make any modifications to the example? If not then we would have to guess what is different in your run to produce radically different results.

Comment: Try a smaller learning rate. Also, post the configuration of your network - loss function, learning rate, weight initialization method. These are all common culprits.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I simply did a copy-paste of the code from Keras website, no modifications

Comment: This doesn't happen when I'm training on CPU, on CPU it successfully trains to 99.2 % val-accuracy after 12 epochs

Comment: After trying out everything with tensorflow and keras, I installed pytorch and fastai, that did not work either. I used the example from https://github.com/fastai/fastai/blob/master/examples/cifar.ipynb and the loss became nan in first epoch.